# Preg_Replace pattern in a template

Tags: php, preg-replace, pattern-matching, datatemplate, template-engine

I am struggling with a way to make this more efficient. Is it possible to make the loop into a single line?

Edit: looking to replace the loop.

```
$template = "<div>[@ data]</div>";
$arrayData = array('hello', 'hi', 'hola');

foreach ($arrayData as $dataValue) {
    $fillPattern = '/\\[@ data\\]/is';

    $arrayTemplate .= preg_replace($fillPattern, $dataValue, $template);
}

$viewContent = preg_replace($pattern, $arrayTemplate, $viewContent);
```

Comment: This might be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Quasdunk he didn't ask for a code-review, he asked if there's a more efficient way of writing it.

Comment: @alfasin That's just what they do at codereview :)

Comment: Less code != more efficient.

Comment: @Quasdunk not exactly... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq I feel like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ3fjQa5Hls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, why you put the assignment to `$fillPattern` in the loop? Its value doesn't change for each iteration. You should put those statement outside the loop, before it. Like this:

```
$template = "<div>[@ data]</div>";
$arrayData = array('hello', 'hi', 'hola');
$fillPattern = '/\\[@ data\\]/is'; //<-- put it here

$arrayTemplate = '';
foreach ($arrayData as $dataValue) {
    $arrayTemplate .= preg_replace($fillPattern, $dataValue, $template);
}
```

Secondly, you already have a way to make the loop into one line. Just use shorter variable names, remove the curly braces (because it is only one statement inside it), and write those 2 statements into one line. Like this:

```
$tpl = "<div>[@ data]</div>";
$data = array('hello', 'hi', 'hola');
$pat = '/\\[@ data\\]/is';

$res = ''; foreach ($data as $val) $res .= preg_replace($pat, $val, $tpl);
```

But if you don't like the shorter variable names, good luck man. I don't think you can make a one line code with those long variable names. Except, you have a loooong looong line :D

For the loop replacement, you should have an understanding about the functional programming. You can use `array_map` to replace the loop. To make it one line code (or one statement code I guess), you have to utilize anonymous function as the argument for `array_map`.

With PHP 5.3 or newer you can use this code:

```
$arrayTemplate = join('', array_map(
    function($x) use ($fillPattern, $template) {
        return preg_replace($fillPattern, $x, $template);
    }, $arrayData));
```

But if you don't have PHP 5.3 or newer, you can use `create_function` like this:

```
$arrayTemplate = join('', array_map(
    create_function('$x', 'global $fillPattern, $template;
        return preg_replace($fillPattern, $x, $template);'
    ), $arrayData));
```

With the shorter variable names above, these code can be rewriten as follows:

```
$res = join('', array_map(function($x) use ($pat, $tpl) {
    return preg_replace($pat, $x, $tpl);
}, $data));
```

or:

```
$res = join('', array_map(create_function(
    '$x', 'global $pat, $tpl; return preg_replace($pat, $x, $tpl);'
), $data));
```

You see, PHP was originally an imperative procedural language. It is not designed as a functional language in the first place. So, I guess the imperative way using foreach loop is still the better way to do it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `$arrayTemplate` to an empty string before you start the loop:

```
$template = "<div>[@ data]</div>";
$arrayData = array('hello', 'hi', 'hola');
$arrayTemplate = ''; // <-- you forgot to declare this

foreach ($arrayData as $dataValue) {
    $arrayTemplate .= preg_replace('/\\[@ data\\]/is', $dataValue, $template);
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/OuxEUT

Comment: Well, yeah, but I mean by not having a loop.

Comment: @osoclever - I don't know of any way to do this without a loop, but I don't think this is inefficient...